# Calendar: doesn't work base_url()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to use a Codeigniter "classic" calendar library:

```
class My_calendar extends CI_Controller{
    function showcal ($year=NULL, $mounth=NULL) {
        echo "Select".br(3);
        $pref = array (
            'show_next_prev'=>'TRUE',
            //'next_prev_url'=> base_url().'my_calendar/showcal'
            'next_prev_url'=>base_url() .'my_calendar/showcal'
        );
        var_dump($pref);
        $this->load->library('calendar',$pref);
        echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $mounth);
    }
```

**Config.php:**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

**System->libraries->Calendar.php:**

```
var $show_next_prev = TRUE;
var $next_prev_url  = '';
```

When I click "<<" or">>" to change month&year it displays message:

> **"404 Page not Found-The paged you requested was not
>   found"**

PS: When I used var_dump($pref)..it displays:

```
'show_next_prev' => string 'TRUE' (length=4)
'next_prev_url' => string 'http://localhost/my_calendar/showcal'
```

Comment: if you mouse hover the << or  >> link what link it shows? and when you get the error message what is link it is showing at your address bar?

Comment: have you tried to set your base_url() ?

Comment: <strong>To Shaiful Islam</strong>: if I hover on "<<" or ">>" displays localhost/my_calendar/2015/07. Getting the error,on the adress bar it shows the same thing: localhost/my_calendar/2015/07.<br><strong>To aizele:</strong> The way I must to set my base_url() is: $config['base_url'] = '' from config.php. If I missed other base_url() settings plese let me know. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I forgot: **autoload.php**, the settings are: **$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url', 'html', 'file')**;

Comment: I didn't solve the problem yet. Could somebody help **why doesn't work the base_url()?** Thanks.

Comment: Finally I got the point, it was from the routes.php. Thanks